# How to remain to show tooltip even when mouseout to outside of the graph component [Highcharts]

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, tooltip

I was wondering if anyone could help me out, around Highcharts

#### What I want to do

Disable to hide the tooltip when mouseout, instead I'd like to hide it on click.

#### Step

1. When hovering over a point in the graph, the tooltip comes up.
2. When moving a cursor(mouseout) outside of the graph component

#### Expected behavior

Still remain to show the tooltip. And enable to hide it by clicking.

#### Actual behavior

Hide the tooltip on mouseout.

#### Code

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-starter-typescript-52vvg4?file=App.tsx

#### Gif

https://gyazo.com/4fa944c5ccad77034d88c2ca54593f96

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning, disable the method responsible for hiding tooltip

```
Highcharts.Pointer.prototype.reset = function () {
    return undefined;
};
```

Add the code for disable the tooltip after window click

```
window.addEventListener("click", function() {
  chart.update({
    tooltip: {
      enabled: false
    }
  });
});
```

Then use the 'mouseOver` function, to re-enable the tooltip when mouse over the point.

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      point: {
        events: {
          mouseOver: function() {
            this.series.chart.update({
              tooltip: {
                enabled: true
              }
            })
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.point.events.mouseOver

**Simplified demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dv5nuzq1/

Comment: Hi @magdalena. Thank you so much for your answer! I'm sure that your way works fine. But, at the same time, I got a reply on the github issue with another more straightforward solution (https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react/issues/371), which resolved my issue. Thank you thou!